# Фигуры в HTML

Tags: html

Мне нужно создать 2 цветных прямоугольники без использования картинок и частично наложить их друг на друга.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="color_1"></div>
<div class="color_2"></div>
```

css:

```
.color_1,.color_2{
  display:block;
  width:100px;    /* ширина каждого блока */
  height:100px;   /* высота каждого блока */
  position:relative;
}
.color_1{
background:#ffffff; /* фон, цвет белый */
left:0px;top:0px; /* позиция элемента относительно его текущей позиции */
}
.color_2{
background:#000000; /* фон, цвет чёрный */
left:0px;top:0px; /* позиция элемента относительно его текущей позиции */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для этого предназначен z-index, например:

```
<head>
<style>
#one {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
        background-color: red;
}
#two {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 150px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
        background-color: black;
}
</style>
<head>
<body>
    <div id="one"> 
    </div> 
    <div id="two"> 
    </div> 
</body>
```

даст наложение черного прямоугольника на красный.